# Regex to match only letters between two words

Tags: python, regex

Say that I've these two strings:

```
Ultramagnetic MC's
```

and

```
Ultramagnetic MC’s <-- the apostrophe is a different char
```

in Python, but generally speaking, how do I write a regex to match the first string letters against the second one?

I mean I'd like to match only letters between two strings and ignore special characters, so I'd be able to match `Ultramagnetic MCs` in a string like this:

```
"Ultramagnetic Mc!s"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "match the two entities"?

Comment: You mean the character class `['\`]`?

Comment: I mean that first string is matched against the second

Comment: @Explosion Pills yes and any other non-letter char

Comment: You need to rewrite your question, it's really hard to make sense out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
import re
def equal_letters(x, y):
     return re.sub(r'\W+', '', x) == re.sub(r'\W+', '', y)

>>> equal_letters("Ultramagnetic MC's", "Ultramagnetic MC’s")
True
>>> equal_letters("Ultramagnetic MC's", "Ultramagnetic Foo")
False
```